# ActiveDirectory access for users on Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

Do users on a machine that runs Windows Sevrer 2008 R2 and is part of an Active Directory Group have access to the ActiveDirectory, e.g. read out attributes of AD records etc. on the DC?

If they can read such information, how can I prevent them from doing so?

I would like to add a custom attribute to the user class which contains a secret used for encryption and decryption. This should of course not be public to any other users.

Comment: What attributes are you concerned about them reading?  Authenticated users have privileges to read a lot of things by default, but not everything (e.g.passwords).

Comment: I have clarified my post

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where do I store sensitive data within Active Directory?](http://serverfault.com/questions/181669/where-do-i-store-sensitive-data-within-active-directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are local users on the server, then no. If they are AD users, then yes. If they are local users and the local user accounts are members of an AD group, then possibly.

One way to find out is by using effective Permissions in advanced security. This will display exactly what permissions a user has over a specific item (e.g. file share, another user object, etc.).